# How do I convert HTML to Markdown in iOS/OS X? Any way to use pandoc in the app?

Tags: objective-c, ios, haskell, markdown, pandoc

I have an HTML string that I'd like to convert to markdown. The best tool I've found to do this is pandoc, which is written in Haskell. How can I get pandoc to run inside a Mac/iOS app? I've heard of compiling Haskell to ARM for incorporation into an iOS project, but I have no idea how to actually get pandoc to compile and work inside an Objective-C app.

Thanks,
Robert

Comment: Stackoverflow seems to work best if you take multi part questions like yours and break it into several narrow questions. Also most people feel better about help when you have made progress on you own between questions. In your case figuring out how to call Haskell code from objective C on make and then coming back and asking "How do I get this running on arm/iphone now?"

Answer (score 2):

I will attempt to help you on how you use pandoc from objective-c part of your question.  Objective-C is a superset of C, or so I have been told, meaning valid C code is valid Objective-C code.

So you question could have been worded how do I call haskell from C, which there is a [nice wiki page about](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Calling_Haskell_from_C).

How you get all of this working on IOS and arm is another ball of yarn and would be more likely to be answered when broken into another question.